# How to structure Redis for data schemas with too many associations - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, redis

I have an application with more than 10 individual data models. Each of this model is associated with one another so deeply. For example there is a model called user that is associated to other data models like posts, comments, replies, connections etc. I am trying to have a redis cache system that will cache the data everytime a query is made. So consider this scenario where a post is upvoted, when this query happens I will have to update all the models that is somehow associated to this query.

So my question is how to structure my redis cache system so that all related data are updated everytime the query is made.

Comment: How many hierarchy levels do u have?

Comment: Seems a broad question,

Answer (score 1):

That is a very broad question. I don't know what your db schema and those entity relations look like. But I have few suggestions which I hope will guide you in a way to structure your data.

**Break down your entities**
Store `user, post, comment, reply` separately. When you need to get a `post` for example, get post and all its entities separately from redis then merge them to build a response.

Something like `POST:345`, `USER:23`, `COMMENT:567`.

**Don't store everything in redis**
Maintaining cache is way more difficult. Store only the data you are accessing more frequently and which will really make an impact if you serve it from cache. For example storing user profile will improve `all post responses`, `comment responses`, `connection lists` etc because all of them will have user objects and you will have them cached.

**Increment stats directly in redis**
Likes and comment count values can directly `increment` and `decrement` in redis.

**Invalidate cache on update**
When an entity is updated, don't update its cache. Simply just delete it from cache and next `get` call will cache the updated data. That is just to simplify things in code.